# Doubts about translation from Nosferatu 1922

Tags: meaning, translation, german-to-english, blackletter

Hello fellow German speakers. I was looking for a nice and joyful discussion about the translation of the great great 1922 movie Nosferatu. I find really interest the many meanings of the subtitles and one that catch my sight was the following one:

[image]

I watched the version with the text in English and the most use is

> Beware that his shadow doth not burden your dreams with horrible fears.

In the German version the text, I believe is a little different.
Any interpretation is welcome.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100612/discussion-on-question-by-raphael-flato-doubts-about-translation-from-nosferatu).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not so easy to translate that phrase for two reasons.

The first difficulty is the word *Alp*. Usually *Alp* is translated as *nightmare* today. You can learn more about the original meaning by visiting the Wikipedia links provided by Carsten [Alp - folklore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alp_(folklore)) and [Mare - folklore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mare_(folklore)#Germany). For reasons of simplification I will use the term *nightly [demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon)* here.

The second difficulty is the use of *beschweren*. The meaning here is not *to complain* but *to ballast* or *to weight down*. Today one would rather say something like *belasten*.

So the translation of the phrase

> Habet acht auf dass euch nicht sein Schatten als wie ein Alp mit grausigen Träumen beschwere.

would be something like

> Watch out that his shadow doesn't weight you down with gruesome dreams like a nightly demon.

Comment: thanks a lot my friend Olafant, your time and notes will be forever estimated! the google translate identified beschwere like complain like you said it would. Living and learning...

Comment: After thinking over it a while, _demon_ seems to be better express the nature of an _Alp_ than _ghost_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah, I think you're right. Demon is much better. Thanks.

Comment: Another English translation for "*sich beschweren*" could be "to burden yourself*"

Comment: I think it’s “weigh down”.

Comment: I'd suspect that _"Take care that his shadow doesn't oppress you with gruesome dreams like a nightly demon."_ would be a more appropriate translation.

Comment: I think *to oppress* fits really well in that context and also *to burden*. The meaning of *to weigh down* might be a little different from *to weight down*. But imo it would also fit well. At the end of the day (pun intended) it may be a little different from person to person, what the demon is able to do to them.

Comment: many thanks for all the thoughts. between oppress and weight down, I think I stick with the weight down, just because the sight of the demon staying sit down on the painting of Johann Heinrich Füssli (in the link from Carsten) give me the sensation of a weight .
And just for curiosity, I am from brasil so I am leaving my translation to Portuguese..."tenha cuidado para que sua sombra nao preencha seu sono com terríveis demonios"

Comment: ahhh, anyone knows how I can get a audio saying this quote in German? not the google's voice please haha. thanks

Comment: @RaphaelFlato   Here you are with a record: https://www.spreaker.com/user/11419575/habetauchtaufdasseuchnichtseinschatten-c

Comment: ohhh boy, all you are the best! thanks christian!